# JQuery script probably syntax mistake

Tags: jquery, html, css

I don't know JQuery, I have a script.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var main_nav = $("#main-nav");
  var main_section = $("#main-section");
  var main_footer = $("#main-footer");
  var main_nav_position = main_nav.position();

  $(window).scroll(function()
  {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= main_nav_position.top)
    {
      main_nav.addClass("main-nav-sticky");
      main_section.addClass("sticky-adjust");
      main_footer.addClass("sticky-adjust");
    }
    else
    {
      main_nav.removeClass("main-nav-sticky");
      main_section.removeClass("sticky-adjust");
      main_footer.removeClass("sticky-adjust");
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
  switch (window.location.pathname)
  {
    case 'index.html':
    $('#shop-button').attr('id','shop-button-disabled');
    break;

    case 'staff.html':
    $('#staff-button').attr('id','staff-button-disabled');
    break;

    case 'contact.html':
    $('#contact-button').attr('id','contact-button-disabled');
    break;
  }
});
```

The first script works very well but second doesn't. I don't know if that's because of the $(document).ready(function() or because of the switch-case istance. Is there some problem or is a CSS/HTML fault?
Thanks!

Comment: no error in console ? Then put a breakpoint to check what happens (for example what's the value of `window.location.pathname`)

Comment: Please provide a better problem description than "it doesn't work". That's not useful at all. Whether there is a syntax or runtime error, you can find out by looking at the console. [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820).

Comment: Looks fine to me, If anything it should at least execute without error.

Comment: There is no error in the code you've provided... what do you mean by "not working" ..? as a side note: you don't need two separate handlers for `ready()` function...

Comment: you are missing a '/' before each case

Comment: Start debugging a problem like this by figuring out exactly what part of the code isn't doing what you expect. Next, begin console.logging the variables in that area, looking for anything suspect. For example, `console.log(window.location.pathname)` This will tell you two things: First, it will tell you if the second snippet is being reached, then it will tell you what the value is so that you can see which switch case (if any) it should have moved on to.

Comment: In which sense "error in console"? Do you mean the browser console? I don't know JQuery or Javascript or any other programming language. I have a scholastic knowledge of C. I'm using JQuery only for these "little tricks". Doesn't work namely it doesn't give me a graphic result. If you tell me that the code it's ok (syntax and content), I will search for HTML/CSS mistakes...

Comment: F12 opens the console in most browsers. Your problem isn't html/css/js related, it's more of a logic problem. The conditions you are using for your switch statement never happen, therefore none of the code in that section ever executes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned from `window.location.pathname` always starts with `/`, so you should change your switch statement to reflect this

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 switch (window.location.pathname)
 {
  case '/index.html':
   $('#shop-button').attr('id','shop-button-disabled');
   break;

  case '/staff.html':
   $('#staff-button').attr('id','staff-button-disabled');
   break;

  case '/contact.html':
   $('#contact-button').attr('id','contact-button-disabled');
   break;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.pathname` probably includes the leading `/`

Also, if you use a default without redirecting it may be only a `/`

For instance, if you browse to http://www.google.com, window.location.pathname will be '/', but if you go to http://www.google.com/webhp, even though it is the same page, pathname will be '/webhp'